# If x comments in a post move post to category y

Tags: categories, comments, count

If a post has 0 comments do nothing.

If a post has 1 comment move the post to category 1.

If a post has 2 comments move the post to cayegory 2.

If a post has 3 comments or more move to category x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [wp_insert_comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_comment/) action to detect when new comments are added to a post. Then on your action callback, you'd the post's comment count with [get_comments_number()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number/), and change post categories with [wp_set_object_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/).

Something along these lines,

```
add_filter(
    'wp_insert_comment',
    function($id, $comment) {
        if ( (int) $comment->comment_approved ) {
            $post_id = (int) $comment->comment_post_ID;
            $post_comment_count = get_comments_number(
                $post_id
            );

            if ( $post_comment_count > 3 ) {
                wp_set_object_terms(
                    $post_id, 
                    array('3-comments'), 
                    'category', 
                    false // don't append, overwrite terms
                );
            } else if ( $post_comment_count === 2 ) {
                wp_set_object_terms(
                    $post_id, 
                    array('2-comments'), 
                    'category', 
                    false // don't append, overwrite terms
                );
            } else {
                wp_set_object_terms(
                    $post_id, 
                    array('1-comment'), 
                    'category', 
                    false // don't append, overwrite terms
                );
            }
        }
    },
    10,
    2
);
```